# Camelot - detecting hyperlinks within table

Tags: python, pdf, python-camelot

I am using [Camelot](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to extract tables from PDF files. While this works very well, it extracts the text only, it does not extract the hyperlinks that are embedded in the tables.

Is there a way of using Camelot or a similar package to extract table text and hyperlinks embedded within tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a PDF example?

Comment: Standing to this issue (https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/137), currently, this feature is not implemented in Camelot. 
Not even the tabula library implements this feature.

Comment: Yes this is standing issue is the same one I have. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

most applications such as tablular text extractors simply scrape the visible surface as plain text and actually hyperlinks are often stored elsewhere in the pdf which is NOT a WTSIWYG word processor file.

So, if you're lucky you can extract the co-ordinates (without their page allocation like this)

```
C:\Users\lz02\Downloads>type "7 - 20 November 2022 (003).pdf" |findstr /i "(http"
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 69.75 299.75 280.63 313.18] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://www.bbc.co.uk/complaints/complaint/) >>/StructParent 5>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 219.37 120.85 402.47 133.06] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://www.bbc.co.uk/complaints/handle-complaint/) >>/StructParent 1>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 146.23 108.64 329.33 120.85] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://www.bbc.co.uk/complaints/handle-complaint/) >>/StructParent 2>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 412.48 108.64 525.55 120.85] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://www.ofcom.org.uk/tv-radio-and-on-demand/broadcast-codes/broadcast-code) >>/StructParent 3>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 69.75 96.434 95.085 108.64] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://www.ofcom.org.uk/tv-radio-and-on-demand/broadcast-codes/broadcast-code) >>/StructParent 4>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 69.75 683.75 317.08 697.18] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://www.bbc.co.uk/complaints/comp-reports/ecu/) >>/StructParent 7>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 463.35 604.46 500.24 617.89] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://www.bbc.co.uk/contact/ecu/reporting-scotland-bbc-one-scotland-20-december-2021) >>/StructParent 8>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 463.35 577.11 500.24 590.54] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://www.bbc.co.uk/contact/ecu/book-of-the-week-preventable-radio-4-19-april-2022) >>/StructParent 9>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 463.35 522.4 521.41 535.83] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://www.bbc.co.uk/contact/ecu/the-one-show-bbc-one-6-october-2022) >>/StructParent 10>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 463.35 495.04 518.04 508.47] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://www.bbc.co.uk/contact/ecu/news-6pm-bbc-one-22-september-2022) >>/StructParent 11>>
<</Subtype/Link/Rect[ 463.35 469.04 518.04 482.47] /BS<</W 0>>/F 4/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://www.bbc.co.uk/contact/ecu/news-1030am-bbc-news-channel-20-september-2022) >>/StructParent 12>>
```

**NOTE, the random order**, to find which page they belong to you need to traceback to their /StructParent  ##